# Azure ServiceBus how far ahead in time can you schedule messages

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

With Azure Service Bus you can use ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc to schedule a message. But I haven't been able to find any information about how far in the future you can schedule. Is it impacted by other ASB settings? Can it be like a year ahead or?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

[ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/f83d1822f337c7eb2d8d4014b4932eb81a9b2979/sdk/servicebus/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/src/Message.cs#L266) is a `DateTime`, it can be set as any value that is less than `DateTime.MaxValue`(Friday, December 31, 9999 11:59:59 PM).

So yes, you can set it as one year later. But as per this [github issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/issues/332#issuecomment-584711845) mentions: service bus is a messaging solution, not a storage. You'd better not set it as long as one year.

Comment: Well read the same too but not an answer to my question. To build a solid solution it would be great to get some more insight into the internals and a kind of SLA for these kinds of features

Comment: @RasmusChristensen, agreed. you can directly add the comment to the [github issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/issues/332#issuecomment-584711845).

Comment: Already asked for a comment, kind of the same question, let's see where we get the answer :)

Comment: @RasmusChristensen, you can also put your idea [here: How can we improve the Windows Azure Service Bus?](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/216926-service-bus). And if the answer is helpful, could you please accept it as answer?